# Rebuild xml with xslt : copy all elements and apply function on some attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is a sample message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>xxx</id>
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <atom:id>atom_id_01</atom:id>
        <atom:content type="application/xml">
            <event xmlns="http://event" xmlns:sample="unknown_namespace" id="event_id_01" type="special_type">
                <sample:product a="a_01_before" b="b__01before" />
            </event>
        </atom:content>
    </atom:entry>
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <atom:id>atom_id_02</atom:id>
        <atom:content type="application/xml">
            <event xmlns="http://event" xmlns:sample="unknown_namespace" id="event_id_02" type="special_type">
                <sample:product a="a_02_before" b="b_02_before" />
            </event>
        </atom:content>
    </atom:entry>
</root>
```

1. Extract entry node
2. Apply a function (ConvertUtil.change(String value)) on product/@a and prodcut/@b.

The result should be like:

```
<entries>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <content>
            <event xmlns="http://event" id="event_id_01" type="special_type">
                <product a="a_01_after" b="b_01_after"/>
            </event>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <content>
            <event xmlns="http://event" id="event_id_02" type="special_type">
                <product a="a_02_after" b="b_02_after"/>
            </event>
        </content>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

I tried in many ways and found out the namespaces were so annoying. Do I need to remove namespace first?

--- Update  ---

I applied it with two xslt files.

The first one will build a new format xml file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <entries>
            <xsl:for-each select="//*[@type='special_type']">
                <xsl:copy-of select="../.."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </entries>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second one will apply a function on some attributes

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:utils="com.example.util">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*/@a | //*/@b">

        <xsl:variable name="aTemp" select="..//@a"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="bTemp" select="..//@b"></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:attribute name="a">
            <xsl:value-of select="utils:ConverterUtil.test($aTemp)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:attribute name="b">
        <xsl:value-of select="utils:ConverterUtil.test($bTemp)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, it kinda works in some weird way. And I don't like it because some expressions like `//*/@a` are very dependent on the condition that `a` attribute will only appear once. Is there any better way?

For example, `product/@a` is better since it depends on the whole xml structure. But I found out that I need to explicitly specify namespace before element like `sample:product/@a`. The problem is in my case the namespace is varying all the time.

Comment: Can you give us the XSLT that is closest to what you want and specify what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample stylesheet to get you started:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:event="http://event"
    xmlns:sample="sample" exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="atom:root">
        <entries>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </entries>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="atom:root/atom:id|atom:entry/atom:id"/>

    <xsl:template match="atom:entry">
        <xsl:element name="entry" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="atom:content">
        <xsl:element name="content" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="event:event">
        <xsl:element name="event" namespace="http://event">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='product']">
        <xsl:element name="product" namespace="http://event">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Do your attribute templates here. Below is just a sample -->
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='product']/@a">
        <xsl:attribute name="a_test">changed_att</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! One of the problem is that the namespace `xmlns:sample="sample"` is unknown. In my case, `sample` has more than  ten namespaces. My app needs to apply xslt to all the products. Each product has a namepsace. Sigh...

Comment: @SanLee What do you mean by "unknown"? Will the XML contain **new** namespaces that you cannot anticipate at the time of writing the XSLT?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, sample namespace is uncertain for writing xslt. For example, a.xml would have namespace `xmlns:sample=sample_a_namespace'`, b.xml would have namespace `xmlns:sampe=sample_b_namespace`

Answer (score 0):

Try something ;like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:event="http://event">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>   

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/atom:root">
    <entries>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </entries>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="event:event/*[local-name()='product']">
    <event:product>
        <xsl:attribute name="a">
            <xsl:value-of select="utils:ConverterUtil.test(@a)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="b">
            <xsl:value-of select="utils:ConverterUtil.test(@b)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </event:product>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```